# Convert XML to Map of nested maps

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, xstream

I have an XML with nested elements and repeating tags. For example:

```
<person>
    <name>Rama</name>
    <age>27</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <address>
        <doornumber>234</doornumber>
        <street>Kanon</street>
        <city>Hyderabad</city>
    </address>
    <qualification>
        <degree>M.Sc</degree>
        <specialisation>Maths</specialisation>
    </qualification>
    <qualification>
        <degree>B.E.</degree>
        <specialisation>Electrical</specialisation>
    </qualification>
</person>
```

Now I want an API which will convert this XML into a Map of Maps in Java:

```
{name="Rama",age="27",gender="male",address={doornumber=234,street="Kanon",city="Hyderabad"},qualification=[{degree="M.Sc",specialisation="Maths"},{degree="B.E.",specialisation="Electrical"}]}
```

I know that we can use XStream API to achieve this. Here I just wanted to know if using XStream has any downsides and whether there exists any other better Java API for achieving this. Any suggestions?

Note: This should be done in a generic way i.e. the Java API should be applicable to any XML, not just to the above XML.

Comment: Hey, if the API works for you, use it, also fyi this will probably end up being primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 5):

It's very late though. But I've written a custom MapEntryConverter for XStream API which can handly any complexity of XML data, no matter how deep it is. Even it'll support Duplicate tag names (which will be stored as ArrayList).

```
XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xStream.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter());
xStream.alias("xml", java.util.Map.class);

// from XML, convert back to map
Map<String, List<Object>> map = (Map<String, List<Object>>) xStream.fromXML(xmlData);
/*System.out.println("MAP: \n" + map.entrySet().toString());*/

String xml = xStream.toXML(map);
/*System.out.println("XML: \n"+xml);*/
```

MapEntryConverter.java

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

public class MapEntryConverter implements Converter{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        AbstractMap<String, List<?>> map = (AbstractMap<String, List<?>>) value;
        List<Map<String, ?>> list = (List<Map<String, ?>>) map.get("xml");
        for( Map<String, ?> maps: list ) {
            for( Entry<String, ?> entry: maps.entrySet() ) {
                mapToXML(writer, entry);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void mapToXML(HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, Entry<String, ?> entry) {
        writer.startNode(entry.getKey());
        if( entry.getValue() instanceof String ) {
            writer.setValue(entry.getValue().toString());
        }else if(  entry.getValue() instanceof ArrayList ) {
            List<?> list = (List<?>) entry.getValue();
            for( Object object: list ) {
                Map<String, ?> map = (Map<String, ?>) object;
                for( Entry<String, ?> entryS: map.entrySet() ) {
                    mapToXML(writer, entryS);
                }
            }
        }
        writer.endNode();
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
        map = xmlToMap(reader, new HashMap<String, List<Object>>());
        return map;
    }

    private Map<String, List<Object>> xmlToMap(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, Map<String, List<Object>> map) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        while(reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            if( reader.hasMoreChildren() ) {
                list.add(xmlToMap(reader, new HashMap<String, List<Object>>()));
            }else {
                Map<String, Object> mapN = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                mapN.put(reader.getNodeName(), reader.getValue());
                list.add(mapN);
            }
            reader.moveUp();
        }
        map.put(reader.getNodeName(), list);
        return map;
    }

}
```

Do note that each value in Map is stored as a list if it has any children. The unmarshalling part is quite neat according to me. I'll polish and simplify the marshalling part in free time.

Input data should be provided within xml tag like below.

```
<xml>
    <person>
        <name>Rama</name>
        <age>27</age>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <address>
            <doornumber>234</doornumber>
            <street>Kanon</street>
            <city>Hyderabad</city>
        </address>
        <qualification>
            <degree>M.Sc</degree>
            <specialisation>Maths</specialisation>
        </qualification>
        <qualification>
            <degree>B.E.</degree>
            <specialisation>Electrical</specialisation>
        </qualification>
    </person>
</xml>
```

There is a little change when comparing my output with your expected output. Duplicate key values are not merged as an array, instead they're of seperate list.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java this project for once to convert xml to json. 
it is fast and does its job.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use the standard JAXP interfaces -- SAX if you really want a map of maps, DOM if you want to preserve order (a tree rather than unordered nested maps) and want APIs which are better mapped to the XML infoset.

Comment: I am looking for a java API which does this instead of working with SAX and DOM parsers.

Comment: There isn't a standard API which does this. Any code which does this is going to invoke a parser under the covers, probably a SAX parser. And using SAX to drive a tree-builder -- which is essentially what you're asking for -- is pretty straightforward; if you're having trouble with it, look at a SAX-to-DOM adapter (widely available as a sample program) and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think Melih might have been referring to this solution. Here is some Kotlin code using the json.org library:

Add `implementation "org.json:json:20180130"` to `build.gradle`.

```
import org.json.JSONML

fun xmlToMap(xml: String): MutableMap<String, Any>? {
    return JSONML.toJSONObject(xml).toMap()
}
```